# What is the equivalent of an ERC20 in EOS?

Tags: tokens, token-registration, token-standard, nft

Ethereum has the basic ERC20 contract to create tokens, but what is the equivalent in EOS? Also what about ERC721 for unique tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are NFT (NON FUNGIBLE TOKENS) ,Ther are the tokens with different values basing on the attributes they posses.
insense always 1 EOS (yours) is equal to 1 EOS (mine) , but not the case in

```
your kitty = my kitty
```

check out this link https://github.com/guoc1995/eosio.nft

Answer (score 2):

## Fungible tokens

The current standard is [`eosio.token`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosio.token).

At the moment, however, the `eosio.token` only issued the system token EOS, and everyone else issuing tokens have to copy the contract to create their own. In the future, Todd Fleming mentioned that there will be a symbol auction process to issue tokens using the main `eosio.token` on mainnet.

## Non-fungible tokens

Right now, there is nothing widely adopted and agreed upon as far as I know, but there is at least one proposal for it, named [`eosio.nft`](https://github.com/unicoeos/eosio.nft):

> The following standard allows the implementation of a standard API for
>   NFTs within EOS smart contracts. This standard provides basic
>   functionality to track and transfer NFTs.